# Converting Float Zip to Nvarchar zip

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database that was originally designed with a column 'Zip Code' set as a float, it contains a 10 digit zip code.

I need to convert it to a 5 digit nvarchar.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[RetailStores]
   SET 
      [ZIP] = LEFT(Str([ZIP CODE], 5, 0),5)

GO
```

This is setting a value of '*****' in the new zip(nvarchar) column I created. Why?

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and output?

Comment: Zip code = 925300000 output on ZIP = "*****"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
[ZIP] = LEFT(Str([ZIP CODE]),5)
```

Or,

```
[ZIP] = LEFT(Str([ZIP CODE],10,0),5)
```

Comment: [ZIP] = LEFT(Str([ZIP CODE]),5) is the answer, I had to run left and right trim also.